# Assigning function output to variable in C gives different output than printing the output directly

Tags: c, function

In my ongoing attempt to learn the C language, I have faced the following setback. I am trying to write a function with returns the time in seconds but with millisecond precision, similar to the Python `time.time()`. Here is the code I wrote to achieve this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

float getTime() {
    // Get the time in seconds (with millisecond precision), e.g. 1656535840.1737888

    // Get spec
    struct timespec spec;
    // Put the current time (ns) into spec
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);
    // Get the time and
    // Jam them together to one float and return
    return ((float) time(NULL)) + (((float) spec.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0f);
}

int main() {
    // Get the time
    float test = getTime();
    // Print it to the screen
    printf("\nAssignment: %f", test);

    // Let's try and make a (pretty bad) clock...

    // Loop...
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i ++) {
        // Print current time
        printf("\nPrinting:   %f", getTime());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As there is no `sleep()` command of some sort, the computer should print the current time to the screen with the string `"Assignment: "`, then immediately continue to print the time with the string `"Printing:   "`. Hence, it should print something like:

```
Assignment: 1633513113.776543
Printing:   1633513113.777353
Printing:   1633513113.778350
Printing:   1633513113.779347
Printing:   1633513113.779347
```

Oddly enough, it prints the following instead:

```
Assignment: 1633513088.000000
Printing:   1633513113.777353
Printing:   1633513113.778350
Printing:   1633513113.779347
Printing:   1633513113.779347
```

The first line (`Assignment: 1633513088.000000`) has a number that completely does not match up to what is expected. The seconds are off (no, there was not a 25 second pause between the 2 prints) and the milliseconds are `0`. I'm not entirely sure even where to start. If the difference is between assigning the value to the variable instead of printing it directly, then what did I do wrong with the assignment? Alas, the output is a float, and the variable `test` is also a float.

What went wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The `float` type does not have enough precision, typically about 7 decimal digits. Please use `double` which has about 16. Never use `float` unless you have a *specific reason* why you can't use `double`.

Comment: Xiddoc, Note `clock_gettime()` is not a standard C function.

Comment: Bad to call `time()` combined with `clock_gettime()`.  Best to use 1 function like `timespec_get()`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly stated by Weather Vane, using a float is not enough for my precision requirement. A double, on the other hand, provided me with exactly what I needed. I made the following changes to my code:

I started by modifying the return calculations to return a `double` instead of a `float`:

```c
return time(NULL) + spec.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0;
```

I then respectively changed the function return type to a `double`:

```c
double getTime() { ... }
```

I also changed the test variable to the `double` type.

```c
double test = getTime();
```

And finally, the result:

```
Assignment: 1633514501.274064
Printing:   1633514501.275059
Printing:   1633514501.276059
Printing:   1633514501.277052
...
```